# How to restore Solr backup from S3 bucket

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, solr, solr-operator

I have an up&running SolrCloud v8.11 cluster on Kubernetes, with solr-operator.

The backup is enabled on S3 bucket.

How can I correctly write the request to perform a `RESTORE` of a backup stored in a S3 bucket?

I'm unable to figure out what should it be the `location` and the `snapshotName` I have to provide in the `Restore API` request made to Solr.

In order to discover those values, I tried to execute the `LISTBACKUP` action, but in this case the `location` values is also wrong...

```sh
$ curl https://my-solrcloud.example.org/solr/admin/collections\?action=LISTBACKUP\&name=collection-name\&repository=collection-backup\&location=my-s3-bucket/collection-backup

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":70},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"specified location s3:///my-s3-bucket/collection-backup/ does not exist.",
    "code":400}}

## The Log in cluster writes:
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: specified location s3:///my-s3-bucket/collection-backup/ does not exist. => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: specified location s3:///my-s3-bucket/collection-backup/ does not exist.
```

After all, the recurring backup works as expected, but sooner or later a `RESTORE action` will be performed and it's not clear how could it be done correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but I came across this question while searching for the same answer. There was [a thread on the mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list?users@solr.apache.org:2022-2:S3%20backup) that helped me to figure out how this is supposed to work.

I found the documentation on this pretty confusing, but the `location` seems to be *relative to the backup repository*. So, the `repository` argument already accounts for the bucket name, and the `name` argument would be the name of the backup you are attempting to list. Solr then builds the S3 path as `{repository bucket} + {location} + {backup name}`. So, location should simply be: `/`

Assume you've set up a `backupRepository` for the SolrCloud deployment like the following:

```
backupRepositories:
- name: "my-backup-repo"
  s3:
    region: "us-east-1"
    bucket: "my-s3-bucket"
```

and you have created a SolrBackup like the following:

```
---
apiVersion: solr.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: SolrBackup
metadata:
  name: "my-collection-backup"
spec:
  repositoryName: "my-backup-repo"
  solrCloud: "my-solr-cloud"
  collections:
    - "my-collection"
```

The full cURL command for LISTBACKUP would be:

```
$ curl https://my-solrcloud.example.org/solr/admin/collections \
  -d action=LISTBACKUP \
  -d name=my-collection-backup \
  -d repository=my-backup-repo \
  -d location=/
```

Similarly for the RESTORE command:

```
$ curl https://my-solrcloud.example.org/solr/admin/collections \
-d action=RESTORE \
-d name=my-collection-backup \
-d repository=my-backup-repo \
-d location=/ \
-d collection=my-collection-restore
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the resolution was to add collection name as suffix as:

`"name" => SolrBackup.metadata.name + '-' + SolrBackup.spec.collection`

From @matthew's example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8983/v2/collections/backups -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
  {
    "list-backups" : {
      "name": "my-collection-backup-my-collection",
      "repository": "my-backup-repo",
      "location": "/"
    }
  }
'
```

[Reference Git Issue](https://github.com/apache/solr-operator/issues/589)